# Mass renaming of randomly named files without knowing their path

Tags: bash, macos

Having an issue during mass renaming of files in a path.

Here is my issue:
I have a drive full of around 16000 or more files (all images, but might be .psd, .jpg, .ai, .png, etc) scattered around in a very messy way, but the filenames are thankfully all unique, but due to the sheer amount, I cant say that's for sure (i mean there might be 2 files named abc.ai or the equivalent, but not many). I cannot know the path, since the csv provided only contains the original filenames, and what they should be renamed to.

Basically, the first line in the csv is something like:

> qwerty.jpg, asdfg.jpg

or

> 123-asd_qwe.ai, abcfgd.ai.

I did try several solutions I found; sed, some scripts, anything I could try I really did.

I would really love to hear propositions or ideas or even a solution!

To note: i tried ::

```
sed 's/"//g' names.csv | while IFS=, read orig new; do echo mv "$orig" "$new"; done
```

and

```
sed 's/^/mv -i -v "/;s/, /" "/;s/$/";/' < names.csv | bash -
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
 while read line          
 do          
      OldImageName=${line%,*}
      NewImageName=${line#*,}
      mv "$OldImageName" "$NewImageName"
 done <"names.csv"
```

Comment: Why are you replacing all the double quotes with nothing in the sed command? Ican't see any quotes in the file.

Comment: I was trying. Just in case the gigantic csv file would happen to have any of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete solution that is working in the specific case described above - It takes duplicate files (in different folders) into consideration and also the naming of the file names (whitespace, accents, etc) do not affect the script. See Solution below:

```
DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"

while read line
do
  OldImageName=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 1) 
  NewImageName=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 2)

  isMatchRelativePath=$(echo $(find . -name "$OldImageName"));
  isMatchNewName=$(echo $(find . -name "$NewImageName"));

  if [ ! -z "$isMatchRelativePath" ];
  then

      find . -name "$OldImageName" -print0 | while read -d $'\0' file
        do

        relativeFolder="${file%$OldImageName}"

        quote1="$relativeFolder$OldImageName";
        quote2="$relativeFolder$NewImageName";

        mv "${quote1}" "${quote2}"
        echo "$relativeFolder$OldImageName, $relativeFolder$NewImageName">>"$DIR/success.csv"
      done


  elif [ ! -z "$isMatchNewName" ]; then
       echo "alreadyRenamed"
      echo "$relativeFolder$OldImageName, $relativeFolder$NewImageName">>"$DIR/alreadyRenamed.csv"
  else
      echo "failed"
      echo "$relativeFolder$OldImageName, $relativeFolder$NewImageName">>"$DIR/failed.csv"
  fi

done <input.csv
```

Comment: This was. Perfect.

Answer (score 2):

If you are absolutely sure of the way the `names.txt` would have the names in the order `oldname,newname` then the below logic should suffice:-

```
#!/bin/bash

 while read line
 do
      # Splitting the line with delimiter as ',' and 
      # getting the fields before and after

      OldImageName=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 1) 
      NewImageName=$(echo $line | cut -d "," -f 2)

      if [ $(find . -name "$OldImageName" | wc -l) -gt 0 ]; then

          # Get the absolute path of the file

          path=$(dirname $(readlink -f "$OldImageName"))

          # Verbose option '-v' for verifying the file rename and 
          # to suppress errors if file not present

          mv -v "$path/$OldImageName" "$path/$NewImageName" 2>/dev/null 
      fi

 done <names.csv
```

Comment: The issue with this is that I am having difficulty knowing where each files are. Paths are not known.

Answer (score 1):

(Rewritten the answer after the question has been clarified in the comments).

The first solution would work only if your CSV contained whole paths, not only basenames. You need to iterate through it, find each file and rename it.

```
sed -r 's/, ?/\t/' names.csv | while IFS=$'\t' read orig new; do 
   find $DIR -type f -name "$orig" | while read path; do
      dirname=`dirname "$path"`
      target_path="$dirname/$new"
      if [[ ! -f "$target_path"]]; then
         mv -v -- "$path" "$target_path"
      else 
         echo "Could not rename '$path' to '$target_path'. Target file exists" >&2 
      fi 
   done
done
```

Replace `$DIR` with the top-most directory. Note I assume each basename may correspond with a number of files in different directories. That is why I iterate through the output of `find`.

Comment: I did try your solutions; the issue is that my csv exists in the root folder, while the files could exist anywhere from that root folder. So I need to find a way to dig for files from ROW-N:COLUMN-1, rename it to ROW-N:COLUMN-1;

Meaning that i should be able to ideally parse a pretty big csv; find where the file (first column of each row) is (find, locate, grep?); then rename it (based on the value from the same row but on column 2).

Really lost as to how to figure this out.

Comment: Removing double-quotes from your expansions is not a way of solving things, but rather a way to fix something just for a little while. Such a code can not be maintained properly, is not be portable and dangerous. Instead of handling two problems by providing separate solutions, handle both at once. Create a robust code. I also would like to suggest to change `mv "$orig" "$new"` to `mv -- "$orig" "$new"`, so that options-like filenames ( e.g. `-m MODE` ) won't be able to change the behavior of `mv`. Moreover - [Useless Use Of Cat](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: @frosty Please tell me if I understand your problem correct now. The CSV file contains only the information about the original basename and the target basename. The task is to find the file by its basename and rename it, not changing its directory.

Comment: Yes, exactly. No paths are available, just the original basenames and the resulting basename.

Comment: Sorry, i meant n-ROW:column1 is initial, then n-ROW:column2 is resulting basename. So sorry for my mistake in my previous comment.

Comment: I adjusted my answer according to your comment. I think you could rephrase the question so that it is a bit clearer.